# Why doesn't Haskell allow more complex infix expressions?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-construction, type-inference

Why doesn't Haskell allow more complex infix expressions, eg.

```
xs `zipWith (+)` ys
l `f 0 0` r
```

It seems to have been [floated](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_expressions) since at least 2007.

[This page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Syntactic_sugar/Cons#Flexibility) suggests that it's because of problems parsing nested infix expressions, eg.

```
x `a `f` b` y
```

But I haven't found any "official" source for a discussion about it. Is this definitely the reason why, and does it preclude anything other than what we currently have? Obviously one simple solution would be to allow any expression that does not itself contain any infix notation, but is that too ad-hoc? Is the ambiguity insurmountable by a compiler, or is it simply regarded that any potential gains are not worth the effort? I can't immediately think of a comparable construct ie. where the "start" and "end" tokens are the same, and thus whether it's a solved problem or not.

Comment: "official" discussion doesn't get too formal.  Often times you're talking about hallway discussions at ICFP and emails on _@haskell.org.  If you are so inclined then write up a proposal and patch set for GHC.

Comment: I don't think you will find a more official answer than what's on the wiki. Infix expressions look like a minor feature for which there's, arguably, very little demand.

Comment: My personal headcanon for how a sensible extension for this would work would be to introduce "\`(" and ")\`" as the start and end tokens. It isn't currently allowed to put anything inside backquotes, so this shouldn't break any existing code, and it ought to make nesting unambiguous. There is some question about whether it could introduce some new ambiguity, though; e.g. consider ```(foo)`bar`(baz)``` which is currently valid and contains both new tokens...

Comment: Strings are an example of a construct with the same start and end token. Which suggests backslash escapes as a possibility for handling nesting. I prefer Daniel Wagner's suggested syntax though. I also lean towards the "you just can't nest them" non-solution, given you can always use `let` binds to avoid the need for nesting, and that's likely to be clearer a lot of the time.

Comment: I have sometimes wanted this feature. The vast majority of the time, I want a simple partial application in the middle. One big example is ``xs `(liftA2 f)` ys`` (where I specifically want `liftA2` and not a combination of `fmap` with `<*>`).

Answer (score 5):

It can be faked

```
import Data.Function ( (&) ) -- = flip ($)

infixl 3
 <|,
 |>

(<|) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(<|) = (&)

(|>) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
(|>) = ($)

as :: Num c => [c] -> [c] -> [c]
as xs ys = xs <|zipWith (+)|> ys

bs :: (Int -> Int -> a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
bs f l r = l <|f 0 0|> r
```

See also [InfixApplicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/InfixApplicative-1.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative-Infix.html)

```
-- >> cs
-- [9,19,29,39,8,18,28,38]

cs :: [Int]
cs = [1..2] <^flip (-)^> [10,20..40]
```

Comment: `infixl 3` seems pretty arbitrary. Why 3?

Comment: I saw some similar things in my searches (guess I should have mentioned it) but was looking for something more directly answering, why doesn't it exist *as part of the language* (either for historical or practical reasons)?